# Google Sheets Trouble with IF, IFS, AND & OR statements

Tags: google-sheets, logical-operators

I can't get the syntax correct for `=ifs(and(C2="Steve",E2<>""), (or(and(D2<>""), C2="Ted", C2="Nancy, C2-"Jane""),"YES","NO"))` I'm Getting a Formula Parse error.

I am trying to return a "YES" if cell E2 is not blank and cell C2 contains one of many possible text strings ("Ted", "Nancy", or "Jane").... or if cell C2 contains text string "Steve", and cell E2 is not blank.

If anything other than the above is true then I want to return a "NO".

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Can't access sample file. Kindly set your spreadsheet to public.

Comment: Sorry - Try this one: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1muj1BNPydrmEdsJ5bUGtp8ZrT9YgG_QahwcUmGZBihE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That's not how this site works. We don't go somewhere else to get information needed for your question - it must all be here, in the question itself. This is clearly stated in the [help] guidelines. If you can't provide the required information here, your question  is not suitable for this site. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved in a different more flexible platform... the answer is here:

```html
=IF(AND(E2<>"",
        OR(C2="Steve",
           AND(D2<>"",OR(C2="Ted",C2="Nancy",C2="Jane")))),"YES","NO")
```